# Tensorflow dynamic/static shapes: Can not convert a int into a Tensor or Operation

Tags: python, tensorflow

In this code, I'm getting the dynamic and static shapes of an input tensor. The problem is that although my Numpy generated array should be considered as a tensor, it does not! Any help will be appreciated!

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


def get_shape(tensor):
    """
        Return the static shape of a tensor only when available
    """

    static_shape = tensor.shape.as_list()
    dynamic_shape = tf.unstack(tf.shape(tensor))

    dim = [s[1] if s[0] is None else s[0] for s in zip(static_shape, dynamic_shape)]

    return dim


a = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 128])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    x = np.random.normal(loc=0.5, scale=0.3, size=[150, 128])
    shapes = get_shape(a)
    print(sess.run(shapes, feed_dict={a: x}))
```

Comment: I think you can't find a static shape for a placeholder, because it's not defined. So that's why you can only find dynamic shape (tf.shape(tensor)

Comment: Why do you pass _shapes_ when `sess.run(a, feed_dict={a: x})` executes ? The type of _shapes_ is `[<tf.Tensor 'unstack:0' shape=() dtype=int32>, 128]`

Comment: @MohanRadhakrishnan Because I want to evaluate the shapes since it  contains a Tensorflow operation.

Comment: @guillaumegg10 Nevermind. the condition inside get_shape handles that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the line

```
dim = [s[1] if s[0] is None else s[0] for s in zip(static_shape, dynamic_shape)]
```

to

```
 dim = [s[1] if s[0] is None else tf.constant(s[0]) for s in zip(static_shape, dynamic_shape)]
```

The thing is that you `s[0]` in this case refers to `int` type, because it's a static shape. But here we need a valid tensorflow operation. Using `tf.constant(s[0])` instead of `s[0]` solves the problem.